# Babel CLI ignores configuration when input is piped

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-cli

This might be a bug in Babel CLI (I'm using 6.24.1), but it appears that Babel doesn't apply `.babelrc` when the source data is being *piped* to it.

---

**Example:**

Given this source file, `foo.js`:

```
const foo = 10;
```

**Good**: This command does what you think it should, with a `.babelrc` in the same directory with the `es2015` preset in it:

```
babel foo.js --out-file foo.classic.js
```

This results in `foo.classic.js`, with properly transpiled content:

```
"use strict";

var foo = 10;
```

**Bad:** This command does not do what you expect:

```
cat foo.js | babel --out-file foo2.classic.js
```

This results in `foo2.classic.js`, with *unchanged* content:

```
const foo = 10;
```

**Good:** This command does what you expect, so it's not the actual configuration at fault:

```
cat foo.js | babel --presets es2015 --out-file foo3.classic.js
```

Result in `foo3.classic.js`:

```
"use strict";

var foo = 10;
```

**Analysis:** In the piping cases, Babel is obviously reading the data from the pipe and passing it out (because the output file gets created), but it appears that Babel completely ignores the `.babelrc` when it gets the data from the pipe.

For reference, this is the `.babelrc` that is supposed to be applied:

```
{
    "presets": [ "es2015" ]
}
```

---

**Why use pipes?**

For what it's worth, you might wonder, "Why pipe input to Babel?  Why not just use files?"

Well, for one thing, piping is a supported feature, so it should "just work."

But in my case, the source files being passed to Babel are themselves the result of a code-generation chain that produces valid ES6 code as output.  It would be nice not to have to have the code generator output a `~temp.js` intermediate file and then have to have it be deleted afterward; it would be far better if the pipes just worked as they're supposed to.

---

**The Question:**

Is this a bug?  If it is, does anyone know of a better workaround than just emitting a file named `~temp.js`, passing that to Babel, and then deleting it?

Comment: How about `babel --out-file foo2.classic.js < foo.js`?

Comment: If that worked (which it doesn't), it would only be suitable if the source is a `.js` file, and it is not: As I said, the JavaScript comes from the `stdout` of another code-generator.  But since `<` produces the same output as the `cat |` version, it's a moot point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently expected behavior, but we've talked about some alternatives in https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/5384.

See [my comment here](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/5384#issuecomment-286504944) for some info. As mentioned in there, the current fix for you would be to do

```
cat foo.js | babel --filename foo.js --out-file foo2.classic.js
```

to tell Babel the filename, so it knows where to search for the `.babelrc` file.

Comment: Well, a little disappointing, but the accepted answer, since it's from an official maintainer. I'm definitely in agreement, though, with `kirs`'s suggestion there to add a `--babelrc` option. It's not complicated to understand (or to implement), is similar to the `--config` options many other tools have (so there's precedent), and it's very predictable in its behavior.

Comment: `kirs` is definitely right about one thing, though: Current behavior absolutely violates the Principle of Least Astonishment, so that alone calls for some kind of change. Either it should read from current directory or add `--babelrc` (or, better yet, do both) to support interaction with `stdin`.

Comment: Yeah I agree the current behavior isn't clear or obvious to people.